# Getting an error message while loading linux OS

Tags: linux, error-handling, boot

I am getting a following error message:

"Error found when loading /home/user/.profile:

/home/user/.profile: line 30: export `=': not a valid identifier /home/user/.profile: line 30:export:` home/user/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/
local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/ga
mes:/snap/bin':not a valid identifier

As a result a session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible."

After using shellcheck.net I corrected both .profiles and .bashrc so it gives no error msg anymore.
Now, when I restart my PC, I get the following msg:
"
/home/user/.profile line 16: /home/user/.bashrc: Permission denied.
"
When I open a terminal the first line is:

```
bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: Permission denied
```

Any ideas on how to proceed ?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: open the file `/home/user/.profile` in an editor, go to line 30 and fix it there.

Comment: Hello KamilCuk: I just checked the line. Here it is: "export PATH = "$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH" .What should I change there ?

Comment: There is a space around `=`. Copy the content of `.profile` file into http://shellcheck.net and fix the mistakes.

Comment: Hey, many thanks for your recommendations ! I followed it and corrected both .profile and .bashrc, there were a lot of corrections. Now, when I restart my PC I get one error message instead: /home/user/.profile: /home/user/.bashrc: Permission denied. Both files have no errors when I shellcheck them ;)

Comment: Looks to me like a system configuration problem. First of all, you should probably go to another site with this, since this is the programmers Q&A, and the problem is not about that. Try this one https://serverfault.com/. Second of all, I can see that you do not have much experience with linux. Perhaps you should start with a friendlier distribution, like ubuntu or fedora, which won't make you configure the login by hand.

Comment: Hello Morse ! Many thanks fr your reply. You are totally right I am new to Linux discovering its possibilities. That is different, but I realised that I did not picked up a right version for me. I should have gone for a LTS version, so I will need to reinstall OS anyway. Thanks for recommending a community, next time I will definitely post such questions there.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I resolved the issue:

I removed the line corresponding to `export PATH` to .bashrc file and removed in from .profiles and the mistake has gone.

However I still have the line on top of my terninal:

```
bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: Permission denied
```